# Updating columns in same table with parallel running Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I've a table looking like:

```
Key   Customer  Attr1   Attr2   Attr3   Attr4   Attr5   ...     Attr70
123   Smith     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ...     NULL
456   Wesson    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    ...     NULL
....
```

This table has a few (about 3) million of rows. 
Each attribute has his own stored procedure with a calculation-logic to fill this column.

Currently those stored procedures are running serial and take quite a while. They're executed like: `EXEC dbo.fill_Attr1 @Customer = 'Smith'` 
  
I've had those stored procedures running parallel (started by a job scheduling tool), but unfortunately every now and then `DEADLOCKS` happened.

What's the best practice to make all (or at least a few) of those SPs running parallel? 
I was thinking about to add `WITH (NOLOCK)` - which i read is not a good practice. 
But as this is happening in a batch process i could gurantee no other process will change or insert data while those SPs are running.

Additional information to make the question clearer. 
Currently those SPs are running serial like:

```
EXEC dbo.fill_Attr1 @Customer = 'Smith'   
EXEC dbo.fill_Attr1 @Customer = 'Wesson'
EXEC dbo.fill_Attr2 @Customer = 'Smith'
EXEC dbo.fill_Attr2 @Customer = 'Wesson'
EXEC dbo.fill_Attr3 @Customer = 'Smith'
EXEC dbo.fill_Attr3 @Customer = 'Wesson'
```

Each stored procedure always updates **all** records of one customer. 
Depending on the logic how to calculate the attribute this might be done in a single update, or - if more complex logic - in several updates within the stored procedure.

Any better idea how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance 
Stefan

Comment: I dont get how it works: EXEC dbo.fill_Attr1 @Customer = 'Smith'  that takes care of attr1 for Smith, and that's it. So it takes 70*3,000,000 or 210,000,000 calls to update the table?

Comment: Can you modify the logic so that only one procedure is used and the update is applied in one go for all the columns?

Comment: @LeeEverest: nope, for each attribute there is one stored procedure. so in total there are 70 SPs

Comment: @RigertaDemiri: possible, but not desired. the whole logic (which is a lot) would be in one SP. so it would run serial again

Comment: @LeeEverest: a StoredProcedure is updating one column. so in my example above, the stored procedure would update all records of Customer = 'Smith' in one update statement within the stored procedure.

Comment: i added some information to - hopefully - make it clearer how the stored procedures are executed

Comment: **Only for testing**, I would put the logic into one stored proc. and enable parallelism on my box. Then I would "force" the query to run in parallel and monitor exec times. Could be that you gain in performance. You could read about each of these steps [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-and-using-parallelism-in-sql-server/), [here](https://littlekendra.com/2016/07/14/max-degree-of-parallelism-cost-threshold-for-parallelism/) & [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4939/how-to-force-a-parallel-execution-plan-in-sql-server-2016/).

Comment: @RigertaDemiri: the update statments in the stored procedures already run in parallelism and DOP 8

Comment: To me, something doesn't *feel* right with this design. Why do you have a stored procedure for each attribute? why do you have so many attributes in the first place? What, if any, is the primary key of this table?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: valid questions! ;-) unfortunately not the best design, indeed. to your questions: yes, there is a key on this table (i just updated the question). there are so many attributes, as they're used for reporting later on in another system (and the interfaces has to be filled with records like [Key],[Customer],[Attr...]). there are so many stored procedures for different reasons: supported by different people, split the logic, be more flexible if not all of them have to be filled,...

Comment: So I would rewrite to update, for each column, all records without the parameter 'Smith'.

Comment: Ok I get your issue now...you want to speed this up but when you exec procs asynchronously, you get deadlocks. So you need to back up a few steps and post the transaction logic of your proc(s). What's happening probably a combination of transactions are taking too long and/or taking out too many locks for your individual updates.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite proc to update *entire column*, not just one user/person/customer 'Smith'.

Comment: this is a comment, not a solution. the stored procedure is already updating ALL records of a Customer, as mentioned in a comment above. not just a single record.

Comment: I"m not sure you follow me - you say ALL records of a Customer.  I'm saying all records of ALL customers in the column. We on the same page?

Comment: i get you. but that's not possible. if the data which is needed to estimate the attributes is ready for one customer, it might not be ready for another customer. as they're coming from different pre-systems. they're not delivered at the same time. thats why the stored procedures have the parameter customer. so: customer A is ready, the chain of the 70 SPs is already starting. maybe a few minutes later data for customer B is ready, now 'his' chain of 70 SPs will start. if those SPs for more than one customer are running at the same time, it will produce deadlocks.